# How to simplify "noun phrase" + "noun phrase" structure

Tags: grammar

Example 1: User 1 and user 2 have the same request.
In this example, I would like to remove the second "user" to shorten the sentence. I wonder if I need to change the first "User" to be "Users". If not, then I do not know how the following writing style is correct.

In our technical writing, we often use "Figs. 1, 2, and 3" to mean "Figures 1, 2, and 3". Since I cannot find a related grammar for such a usage, can anyone give me some hint or tell me which one is correct. (It will be better if there is an explanation)

Another example is to simplify "from user 1 to user 2." I do not know which one of the following two writing is correct: "from users 1 to 2" and "from user 1 to 2."

Thanks!

Comment: You can say **two users have the same request**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the comment, but the above example is only for illustrating my question. In a more "complicated" case, I may not be able to use your suggestion. For example, I wish to simplify "from user 1 to user 2." Here, I do not know which one of the following is correct: "from user 1 to 2" v.s. "from users 1 to 2."

Comment: Simply 'Users 1 and 2 ...'. // 'From user 1 to user 2' is non-reducible.

Comment: Please edit your more "complicated" case into the question. Everyone is responding to the "simple" case because that's the only thing in your question. For example, the case of two users is handled differently from, say nine users. So, again,  please add all of your unstated requirements into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are different from each other.

"User 1 and user 2 have the same request." → "**Users** 1 and 2 have the same request."

"from user 1 to user 2."  → "from user 1 to user 2." (No, you can't simplify, because the direction is required.)

However,
"between user 1 and user 2."  → "between **users** 1 and 2." (Works because it is directionless).